# JSON performance - multi-file vs long single file

Tags: javascript, json

My application has to download and read a lot of data that was originally stored in a database.  I haven't been able to determine whether it's better to break each table into it's own JSON file, or whether I should pack all the data into a single JSON file.  The download would take longer for dozens of files, but the parsing would take longer for the single file.  The answer might be more opinion than fact, but I thought it was worth tapping into SO for insight.

Comment: Do whatever is simplest and then worry about performance if it is too slow.

Answer (score 2):

The users will benefit from small chunks since they can be displayed one at a time and thus giving the user information as soon as it is available. If you have a lot of data to parse it might take too long for the user to stick around or at the very least create some annoyance because your site is too slow.

I would think that the complexity of a JSON.parse(..) would be O(n), so that the total time should be pretty similar whether you chose to parse it all at once or in chunks. Since I couldn't find any information about the actual algorithm implemented I wrote a small simulation which points to chunks actually being marginally faster.

**Google Chrome**

iterations=1000, dataSize=100000, chunks=1000: bigData=3115, **smallData=2331**

iterations=1000, dataSize=100000, chunks=100: bigData=3218, **smallData=2579**

```
<body>
    <div id="resultBigData"></div>
    <div id="resultSmallData"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        // Parameters
        var simulationIterations = 500;
        var sizeOfData = 100000;
        var smallDataChunk = 100;

        // Create data to use in the simulation.
        var bigDataArray = new Array();
        for (var indexBigData = 0; indexBigData < sizeOfData; ++indexBigData) {
            bigDataArray.push(indexBigData);
        }

        var smallDataArray = new Array();
        for (var indexSmallData = 0; indexSmallData < smallDataChunk; ++indexSmallData) {
            smallDataArray.push(indexSmallData);
        }

        // Create a stringified version of the arrays.
        var jsonBigDataArray = JSON.stringify(bigDataArray);
        var jsonSmallDataArray = JSON.stringify(smallDataArray);

        // Run a timed simulation with the bigData array.
        var startTimestampBigDataArray = new Date().getTime();
        for (var indexIterationBigData = 0; indexIterationBigData < simulationIterations; ++indexIterationBigData) {
            JSON.parse(jsonBigDataArray);
        }
        document.getElementById('resultBigData').innerHTML = '<p><b>BigData:</b> ' + ((new Date().getTime()) - startTimestampBigDataArray) + '</p>';

        // Run a timed simulation with the smallData array.
        var startTimestampSmallDataArray = new Date().getTime();
        for (var indexIterationSmallData = 0; indexIterationSmallData < simulationIterations; ++indexIterationSmallData) {
            for (var indexIterationSmallDataCompensation = 0; indexIterationSmallDataCompensation < (sizeOfData / smallDataChunk); ++indexIterationSmallDataCompensation) {
                JSON.parse(jsonSmallDataArray);
            }
        }
        document.getElementById('resultSmallData').innerHTML = '<p><b>SmallData:</b> ' + ((new Date().getTime()) - startTimestampSmallDataArray) + '</p>';
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: I agree that smaller chunks are better when the data is required at varying times during run-time, but I need to load all the data when the application itself loads.  It's all required to even start the application.  Does the small chunk approach still hold in that situation?

Comment: Yes, even though the simulations I ran (included above) themselves are not enough for a definitive answer as to how much faster small chunks are, they are at least *as fast* as a single big chunk [when only working with integers]. If you really need the performance I suggest you try the above code with an example closer to your actual data on a machine that will run your code to see the results.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're talking about client-side javascript in a web page? If so, the multiple files may be better because you can process them in chunks, avoiding warnings from the browser that your script is taking too long. But as Quentin commented, you may find that the performance isn't even an issue.